# add multi reference function type in class

Tags: c++, function, types, reference

I'm not sure its good title for my question but I intend to make parser class which extract data and converted to the desired format in one code line

following is my defined class

```
typedef std::function<void( const char *data)   > Parser;

class parse(){      
public:
  parse(){;}
 Parser parse(inline unsigned char *hex_packet);
{
 sscanf(hex_packet,"%16x%4x",&H_X[16],&H_Y[4]);
}

  int32 get_x(){ return   static_cast<uint32_t>(H_X)&FFFFFFFF);}
  int32 get_y(){ return   static_cast<uint32_t>(H_Y)&FFFFFFFF);}
  private:

uint8_t H_X[16],H_Y[4];         
}
  parse AParser;
int main() { 
    unsigned char d = "0x100FA7464B029C34A";

    printf("Value x=%d Value Y=%d",
           AParser.parse(d).getX(),
           AParser.parse(d).getX());
    }
```

any advise or direct link to toturail is really appreciated

Comment: This will not work. The `sscanf` call is wrong.

Comment: Beside of the fact that you pass `H_X[16],H_Y[4]` (elements instead of addresses where indices are even out-of-bound to make things worse), `"%x"` requires that you pass a pointer to an `unsigned int` (just recalled [`sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to be really correct). Btw. are you aware that an `uint_8` is capable to store a byte which can be described exactly by a _two_-digit hexadecimal number? (That's why hex codes are favored when dealing with binary.)

Comment: thanks, @Scheff for noticing, I forgot to put & sign, however, my main question was, how to make reference function in the class

Comment: The address operators doesn't make it (much) better. It's still wrong type and out-of-bound access.

Comment: @Scheff can you be more specific or provide suggestion to parse the hex code to different data type

Comment: It's a bit difficult. May be, you should try to describe more exactly what you intend to do. Your exposed code isn't much help because it's ful of syntax errors and constructs which... uhmm... doesn't really make sense. E.g. `unsigned char d = "0x100FA7464B029C34A";` a hex-code with 17 digits - could be stored with 9 bytes. You want to parse into 16 + 4. ??? E.g. `class parse()` -> syntax error.  Why a class? Why not just a free-standing function? Furthermore, it seems you didn't understand the concept of arrays...

Comment: Furthermore, `sscanf()` with `"%x"` expects a pointer to `unsigned int` but you don't provide one... Sorry, I simply don't know where to start. The only thing I could do - throwing it all away and write it new but this is not for what SO is intended. (It's not a code writing service.) May be, the best I can recommend, please, get a book to learn C++. Sorry again, no offense.

Comment: Btw. parsing of hex-codes is one of the most asked topics. Haven't you tried to simply google this? E.g. [google `c++ read hex string`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+read+hex+string)

Comment: thanks again @Scheff, but as I mentioned it is just some simple idea about how to make simple reference type function in the  class and parsing the string is just a simple task, although thanks for the tip about to reconsider sscanf function with more care

Comment: Sorry, again. If you haven't experience in C++, this is **not** a simple task - not in C++. Looking at your code, it seems you haven't any experience. If you don't believe me, please, have a look onto this [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efc6d0e098575de3).